# Cordova android getViewTreeObserver with version 4.0.0 and older

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-4

I'm developing a Cordova plugin on Android, but with Cordova Android new version (v 4.0.0) some methods I'm using have changed.

In my plugin.java I am using (on cordova android <= 3.7.1) :

```
//Adding listener on scroll when my plugin is initiated
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);

//Then later
@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
    //custom actions when scrolling
}
```

Seem that now with cordova-android V.4.0.0, the way to access webView has changed

> "onScrollChanged" message removed. Use view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(...) instead

So now I have to do it this way with cordova-android 4.0.0 :

```
webView.getView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);
```

Since my plugin has to be compatible with cordova-android < 4.0.0  and cordova-android >= 4.0.0, I was looking for a simple way to check cordova-android current version in my plugin.java to do one or the other method, but so far I haven't found how to do it...

So is there a public method to access corodova-android from an android plugin ? Have I missed an already common method to all cordova-android version do to what I want ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found for this problem : use of Reflection